# Cannot resolve symbol 'fromJson' in android studio

Tags: android, json

Getting an error as " Cannot resolve symbom fromJson' in the highlighted(**) part.

Converting and decoding each result in the json array into movie objects .
Also, below is the method called in the implemented method of Json.

```
public class BoxOfficeMovie implements Serializable {

private String title;
private int year;
private String synopsis;
private String posterlurl;
private int criticsScore;
private ArrayList<String> castlist;

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public String getSynopsis() {
    return synopsis;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getCriticsScore() {
    return criticsScore;
}

public String getPosterlurl() {
    return posterlurl;
}
public  String getCastList()
{
    return TextUtils.join(",",castlist);

}

public static BoxOfficeMovie fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject)
{
    BoxOfficeMovie b = new BoxOfficeMovie();
    try
    {
        //Deserialize json into object fields
        b.title= jsonObject.getString("title");
        b.year= jsonObject.getInt("Year");
        b.synopsis= jsonObject.getString("synopsis");
        b.posterlurl= jsonObject.getJSONObject("posters").getString("thumbnail");
        b.criticsScore= jsonObject.getJSONObject("ratings").getInt("critics_score");
        // Constrcuting a simple array of cast items
        b.castlist= new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray Cast = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Cast");
        for (int i=0;i<Cast.length();i++)
        {
            b.castlist.add(Cast.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
        }

    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
    return b;
}      

public static ArrayList<BoxOfficeMovie> fromJson(JSONArray jsonArray)
{
    ArrayList<BoxOfficeMovie> movies= new ArrayList<BoxOfficeMovie>(jsonArray.length());
    // Process each result in json Array and convert and deccode into movie object
    JSONObject moviesJson;
    for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        moviesJson = null;
    try
    {
        moviesJson= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    }
    catch (Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    **BoxOfficeMovie movie= new BoxOfficeMovie.fromJson(moviesJson);**
    if (movie!=null)
    {
        movies.add(movie);
    }

    return  movies;
}
```

Comment: You already inside that method,why still need to call ?

Comment: post your JSON data here.

Comment: @JohnJoe To check if the movie is null or not.

Comment: Hi Vipul, where is the function public static BoxOfficeMovie fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject)? Because your calling a function that takes JSONObject as an argument and defined function showed takes an JSONArray.

Comment: @RishabhBhatia    Edited .

Comment: Vipul change BoxOfficeMovie movie= new BoxOfficeMovie.fromJson(moviesJson); to BoxOfficeMovie movie= BoxOfficeMovie.fromJson(moviesJson);

Comment: @RishabhBhatia   thanks. it worked. Can I know the reason ?

Comment: Hi Vipul, i added code with example. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Vipul your fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) function is declared as static. Here

```
public static BoxOfficeMovie fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject)
{
    BoxOfficeMovie b = new BoxOfficeMovie();
    // your code
    return b;
}
```

So you need to change your method call from

```
BoxOfficeMovie movie= new BoxOfficeMovie.fromJson(moviesJson);
```

to

```
BoxOfficeMovie movie= BoxOfficeMovie.fromJson(moviesJson);
```

Static fields and functions are accessed as ClassName.field/function & objects are created to access non-static fields. Hope it helps you.

Lets take a simple example. Suppose we have 2 classes Class A and Class B. Here the code

```
Class A {

    public String name = "classA";   // public non-static

    public static String someFunction() {   //public static
         return "someValue";
    }
}
```

To access the field name and someFunction in another Activity Class B we  write

```
Class B extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // call static function of Class A
        String value = ClassA.someFunction();

        // access private non-static field as 
        ClassA classObject = new ClassA();
        String name = classObject.name;
    }
}
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Vipul If your issue is resolved, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `public static BoxOfficeMovie fromJson(JSONObject jsonObject)` is an static method and you are trying to create an `instance` to `call` this method and that it totally `WRONG`.

No need to create an instance of class `BoxOfficeMovie` to call static method. You can call it using `BoxOfficeMovie.fromJson(moviesJson)`.

**Update your method `fromJson(JSONArray jsonArray)` as below:**

```
public static ArrayList<BoxOfficeMovie> fromJson(JSONArray jsonArray)
{
    ArrayList<BoxOfficeMovie> movies= new ArrayList<BoxOfficeMovie>();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject moviesJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            BoxOfficeMovie movie = BoxOfficeMovie.fromJson(moviesJson);
            if (movie != null) {
                movies.add(movie);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return  movies;
}
```